# Identifying trend with SQL query; code explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to learn T-SQL on my own, studying one of beginner's book. I got stuck on one query and still cannot figure it out; why it works, or  how it works. I hope you can help me.

I've got the table:

```
CREATE TABLE #AnnualSales
(
    YEAR CHAR(4),
    SALE INT
);

INSERT INTO #AnnualSales (YEAR, SALE)
VALUES ('2001', 100), ('2002', 150), ('2003', 120), ('2004', 150),
       ('2005', 250), ('2006', 300), ('2007', 250);
```

The goal is to identify selling trend sorted by years where '1' is positive and '-1' negative trend. The book says we can do it from this (1):

```
WITH Years AS
(
    SELECT 
        Z.Year, Z.Sale, 
        SIGN(Z.Sale - (SELECT W1.Sale
                       FROM #AnnualSales AS W1
                       WHERE W1.Year = (SELECT MAX(W2.Year)
                                        FROM #AnnualSales AS W2
                                        WHERE W2.Year < Z.Year))) AS Trend
    FROM 
        #AnnualSales AS Z
)
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM Years AS T2
     WHERE T2.Year >= T1.Year 
       AND T2.Trend <> T1.Trend) AS Rows
FROM 
    Years AS T1
```

To this (2):

```
WITH Years AS
(
    SELECT 
        Z.Year, Z.Sale, 
        SIGN(Z.Sale - (SELECT W1.Sale
                       FROM #AnnualSales AS W1
                       WHERE W1.Year = (SELECT MAX(W2.Year)
                                        FROM #AnnualSales AS W2
                                        WHERE W2.Year<Z.Year))) AS Trend
    FROM 
        #AnnualSales AS Z
),
Factor AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM Years AS T2
         WHERE T2.Year >= T1.Year AND T2.Trend <> T1.Trend) AS Rows
    FROM 
        Years AS T1
)
SELECT 
    MIN(Year), MAX(Year), Trend
FROM 
    Factor
GROUP BY 
    Rows, Trend
ORDER BY 
    MIN(Year)
```

I don't get how it works from (1) to (2). I don't understand why in query (1) the results show values like '2' and '3', and at the end everything works how it is supposed to.

Comment: If the book tells you to store a value indicating a year as a `char(4)`, you should throw away the book and buy a better book.

Comment: Trying to assess trends without window functions is a fool's errand.

Comment: A useful trick for puzzling out CTEs is to display the intermediate results. You can replace the final `select` with `select * from Years;` or `select * from Factor;` to see the results from those parts of the CTE,

Comment: Which part have you been able the understand so that I could answer accordingly? The `GROUP BY Rows` part is an obfuscated trick, rest should be straight forward.

Comment: The natural solution (since SQL:2003) is to use windows functions.